# Unable to pass variable to python script

Tags: python, curl

I have following code which creates subtask in JIRA

```
inf = open('/var/lib/rundeck/output.txt')
for line in inf:
                print line
                headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
                data = '{"fields":{"project":{"key":"TECH"},"parent":{"key":line},"summary":"Create AD List ","description":"","issuetype":{"name":"Sub-task"},"customfield_10107":{"id":"10400"}}}'
                response = requests.post('https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('user', 'pass'))

inf.close()
```

i have a file (output.txt), python for every line found (TECH-XXX)  printss all lines, it should trigger script above.

when i hard-code key `"key":"TECH-1147"` instead of `"key":line` script generates subtask, but when substituting variable (line), nothing happens

Ouptut.txt:

```
TECH-1234
TECH-1345
.........
```

i convereted this code:

```
curl -D- -u: user:Pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"summary\":\"Create AD List of all Active Users\",\"description\":\"some description\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"},\"customfield_10107\":{\"id\":\"10400\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/
```

using this https://curl.trillworks.com/

tried also {`"key":'"' + line + '"'}`

and getting `{u'errorMessages': [u'The issue no longer exists.'], u'errors': {}}`

Issue is TECH-1247 (variable) which definitely exists

Comment: you are treating line as part of the string, not as a variable

Comment: okay,how to convert it to variable ?

Comment: using string formatting is one way

Comment: okay i tried `data = "%s" % line` and put it "key":data but the same, when hard-code it it works

Comment: After making the string formatting update, have you tried printing `response.json()` (or `json.dumps(resp_json)`) to see what the response looks like? Maybe it will show an error.

Comment: `{u'errorMessages': [u"Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): expected a value\n at`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try using `rstrip()` to trip any trailing whitespace/newlines and `json.dumps()` so the data isn't passed as form-encoded...

```
import requests
import json

with open("output.txt", "rb") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        data = {"fields": {
                "project": {"key": "TECH"},
                "parent": {"key": line.rstrip()},
                "summary": "Create AD List ",
                "description": "",
                "issuetype": {"name": "Sub-task"},
                "customfield_10107": {"id": "10400"}
                }}

        response = requests.post("https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/",
                                 headers=headers,
                                 data=json.dumps(data),
                                 auth=("user", "pass"))
```

Like another answer said, if you use `json` param instead of the `data` param, the dict will automatically be encoded for you and the Content-Type set to application/json.

[See here for more information.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: This is the correct answer, because python does not strip the trailing newline from lines. That is, the key is meant to `"TECH-X"` and not `"TECH-X\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

`line` is not interpreted as a variable. It's just a string. One solution is to use the `%` operator for string formatting:

```
inf = open('/var/lib/rundeck/output.txt')
for line in inf:
    print line
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
    data = '{"fields":{"project":{"key":"TECH"},"parent":{"key":%s},"summary":"Create AD List ","description":"","issuetype":{"name":"Sub-task"},"customfield_10107":{"id":"10400"}}}' % line
    response = requests.post('https://jira.corp.hentsu.com/rest/api/latest/issue/', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('user', 'pass'))

inf.close()
```

Note that `line` was replaced with `%s` and then `% line` was added to the end. This will replace the `%s` with the value of the variable `line`.

Comment: doesn't work, it prints line but not passing to curl

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Also, I don't see where you're using cURL anywhere. You may want to print the value of `data` to make sure it's correct.

Comment: i mean, subtask is not created, it's CURL command just converted to works with python, it prints TECH-1147 (which is parameter for above command)

Comment: `data` should not print `TECH-1147` since it contains a string of JSON...Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "subtask." I'm assuming `requests` is the Python requests library in which case, `requests.post` is just an ordinary Python function.

Comment: it prints because i put `print line` i just updated question-it's bash conmmand converted to work under python

Comment: I understand. I suggested earlier that you print the value of `data` to make sure it's what you expect.